# A site looks different in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to put some small ads on my page. They are showed in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE9. Do you have an idea why?

I haven't tried it in other browser, if you have sometething else (e.g., Safari), it would be great if you could tell me the result. The webiste is [Studentensport.at](http://www.studentensport.at/). There should be 5 small ads at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Have you checked if it has an ad blocker installed/enabled?

Comment: Even Chuck Norris couldn't keep up his round house kicking if he were to go kick everyone who has spoken this question's title.

Comment: It's a freshly installed IE 9, no ad-onds at all. Btw, do you see the ads in IE?

Comment: I haven't tried IE9 yet.  Are you sure it doesn't have a built in ad blocker?  There are some indications that enabling the "do not track" functionality can cause ads to not show.

Comment: I don't see anything... How does it look like in older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it have something to do with this:

```
<img width=""
```

in your image tags? I can see the five divs when I select them, but they're very thin.

Edit. It is. If you explicitly set the height and width or remove the height and width it works.